# SQLAlchemy models vs Pydantic models

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I'm  following this [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases) to adapt it to my needs, in this case, to perform a sql module  where I need to record the data collected by a webhook from the gitlab issues.

For the database module I'm using **SQLAlchemy** library and **PostgreSQL** as database engine.

So, I would like to solve some doubts, I have regarding the use of the **Pydantic** library, in particular with this [example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases)

From what I've read, Pydantic is a  library that is used for data validation using classes with attributes.

But I don't quite understand some things...is the integration of Pydantic strictly necessary? The purpose of using Pydantic I understand, but the integration of using Pydantic with SQLAlchemy models I don't understand.

In the tutorial, `models.py` has the following content:

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))

    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="items")
```

And `schemas.py` has the following content:

```py
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class ItemBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: Optional[str] = None


class ItemCreate(ItemBase):
    pass


class Item(ItemBase):
    id: int
    owner_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str


class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    is_active: bool
    items: list[Item] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I know that the primary means of defining objects in Pydantic is via models and also I know that models are simply classes which inherit from **BaseModel**.

Why does it create *ItemBase, ItemCreate* and *Item* that **inherits from ItemBase?**

In *ItemBase* it passes the fields that are strictly necessary in Item table? and defines its type?

The ItemCreate class I have seen that it is used latter in `crud.py` to create a user, in my case I would have to do the same with the incidents? I mean, I would have to create a clase like this:

```
class IssueCreate(BaseModel):
    pass
```

There are my examples trying to follow the same workflow:

`models.py`

```py
import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import Column, Table
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Datetime, TIMESTAMP

from .database import Base


class Issues(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'issues'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    gl_assignee_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    gl_id_user = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    current_title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    previous_title = Column(String, nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), nullable=False)
    updated_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), nullable=True)
    closed_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), nullable=True)
    action = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

And `schemas.py`

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class IssueBase(BaseModel):
    updated_at: None
    closed_at: None
    previous_title: None

class Issue(IssueBase):
    id: int
    gl_task_id: int
    gl_assignee_id: int
    gl_id_user: int
    current_title: str
    action: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

But I don't know if I'm right doing it in this way, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This may be interesting: https://github.com/tiangolo/pydantic-sqlalchemy

Comment: Just a quick note that  the creator of FastAPI has created SQLModel (https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) to deal with the complexity described in the above.  

With SQLModel you basically declare a single model that does everything, rather than having to make one model for SQLAlchemy and three for Pydantic. Documentation should be updated soon.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The tutorial you mentioned is about FastAPI. Pydantic by itself has nothing to do with SQL, SQLAlchemy or relational databases. It is FastAPI that is showing you a way to use a relational database.

---

> is the integration of pydantic strictly necessary [when using FastAPI]?

Yes. Pydantic is a requirement according to [the documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/):

> ### Requirements
>
> Python 3.6+
>
> FastAPI stands on the shoulders of giants:
>
> - [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/) for the web parts.
> - [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) for the data parts.

---

> Why does it create ItemBase, ItemCreate and Item that inherits from ItemBase?

Pydantic models are the way FastAPI uses to define the schemas of the data that it receives (requests) and returns (responses). `ItemCreate` represent the data required to create an item. `Item` represents the data that is returned when the items are queried. The fields that are common to `ItemCreate` and `Item` are placed in `ItemBase` to avoid duplication.

---

> In ItemBase it passes the fields that are strictly necessary in Item table?  and defines its type?

`ItemBase` has the fields that are common to `ItemCreate` and `Item`. It has nothing to do with a table. It is just a way to avoid duplication. Every field of a pydantic model must have a type, there is nothing unusual there.

---

> in my case I would have to do the same with the incidents?

If you have a similar scenario where the schemas of the data that you receive (request) and the data that you return (response) have common fields (same name and type), you could define a model with those fields and have other models inherit from it to avoid duplication.

---

This could be a (probably simplistic) way of understanding FastAPI and pydantic:

FastAPI transforms requests to pydantic models. Those pydantic models are your input data and are also known as schemas (maybe to avoid confusion with other uses of the word model). You can do whatever you want with those schemas, including using them to create relational database models and persisting them.

Whatever data you want to return as a response needs to be transformed by FastAPI to a pydantic model (schema). It just happens that pydantic supports an [orm_mode](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances) option that allows it to parse arbitrary objects with attributes instead of dicts. Using that option you can return a relational database model and FastAPI will transform it to the corresponding schema (using pydantic).

FastAPI uses the parsing and validation features of pydantic, but you have to follow a simple rule: the data that you receive must comply with the input schema and the data that you want to return must comply with the output schema. You are in charge of deciding whatever happens in between.